# combine background image with gradient doesn't work in my case?

Tags: html, css

demo http://jsfiddle.net/hfkhb9eL/

I used this for gradient 
`background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)100%);` and it work, but after I tried to merge it with a background image it doesn't work, anything wrong with this :

```
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Hsban3N.jpg), -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0)0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)100%);
```

?

Comment: Change the order of the Image and Gradient in your multiple gradient code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you had the image/gradient in the wrong order.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image:
 -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), 
  url('http://i.imgur.com/Hsban3N.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div>hi</div>
```

Basically, the stacking order is first declared is on top and the next is underneath that...and so on.

Comment: Not really except your variable names don't match...but I'm not a JS/JQ expert.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the gradient in :after

```
div:after{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65)100%);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    content:'';
    display:block;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfkhb9eL/1/

Comment: Thanks! any idea why this jsfiddle.net/gsp83wx8 doesn't work?